# Bootstrap Dual List Box Not Sort Alphabetically

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to adjust Alex van den Hoogen's [Boostrap DualListbox](https://github.com/Geodan/DualListBox), so that it doesn't sort the option's in the select list box alphabetically.

I found the javascript function that (I think) sorts them alphabetically:

```
$.fn.sortOptions = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).append($(this).find('option').remove().sort(function(a, b) {
            var at = $(a).text(), bt = $(b).text();
            return (at > bt) ? 1 : ((at < bt) ? -1 : 0);
        }));
    });
};
```

Unfortunately that javascript is a a few levels above my paygrade. **How do I stop it from ordering the `<option></option>` tags alphabetically?**

I'd like to keep them in the order they were when I rendered them in html. Or, if that is not possible I could include some data for ordering ascending numerically:

`data-order="1"...data-order="2", etc`

Comment: Have you tried changing 'return (at > bt) ? 1 : ((at < bt) ? -1 : 0);' to 'return 0' OR 'return 1' How was the list affected?

Comment: I think it's working. It is doing a few odd things with the ordering though :)

Comment: Great :) glad to help

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to delete the contents of the function like this:

```
$.fn.sortOptions = function() {
    return this.each(function() {

    });
};
```